# Get UIImage origin.x from UIImageVIew

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, coordinates

Is it possible to get the X coordinate of a `UIImage`, that is displayed in a `UIImageView` when the view's scale mode is set to `Center`?

Image to better illustrate what I want:

[image: Picture explaining the problem]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pretty much basic maths:

```
CGFloat x = (imageView.frame.size.width - imageView.image.size.width) / 2;
```

Comment: I think `UIImageView` only resizes the image during rendering but no the actual `UIImage` itself.

Comment: Sure.. Just have to wait 10 mins after posting a question

Comment: @H2CO3 You're right. The docs are a bit misleading: "UIViewContentModeCenter - Centers the content in the view’s bounds, keeping the proportions the same.". Technically that would mean it can be resized (just keeping the proportions the same). But `center` actually doesn't resize.

Comment: This of course will never work! You don't get the size of the image relative to the imageview, but the resolution (either real pixels or in points) and this will in most cases result in a negative value!

Comment: @user3892683 That's right. then why this "answer" got upvotes? what's a solid solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think no.

But there is work around solution, you can calculate image height and width and according to that you can calculate centre position by `(imageView.frame.size.width-image.size.width)/2` and same thing for height.

Hope this solves your issue.